# Netbeans intellisense for Yahoo utils

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, intellisense

In netbeans I created an html page in which I am using Yahoo utils.  If I type "yahoo." then namespace, render, hide are not visible in the interactive documentation.  Please tell me how to configure Netbeans to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Netbeans, but I do know that Javascript is case-senstive, and that the global Yahoo object is `YAHOO`, not `yahoo`.

So try it in all caps.